# ReactJS Mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm in the Project component section of my portfolio and trying to connect the weblinks to the 4 different projects.

```
            <div id="portfolio-wrapper" className="bgrid-quarters s-bgrid-thirds cf">
              {
              resumeData.portfolio && resumeData.portfolio.map((item) => {
                return(
                  <div className="columns portfolio-item">
                  <div className="item-wrap">
                      <img src={`${item.imgurl}`} alt="" className="item-imgurl"/>
                      <div className="overlay">
                        <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                          <h5>{item.name}</h5>
                          <p>{item.description}</p>
                          <h6>{item.url}</h6>
                        </div>
                      </div>                   
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
```

```
      {
        "name":"Zesty Investy",
        "description":"Investment calculator that helps plan finances for retirement",
        "url":"https://grocha78.github.io/Zesty-Investy-Calculonesty/",
        "imgurl":"/assets/zestyinvesty.png"
      },
      {
        "name":"Art Garage",
        "description":"The place that brings artists and potential buyers together.",
        "url":"https://art-garage-app.herokuapp.com/",
        "imgurl":"src/assets/artgarage.png"
      },
      {
        "name":"Tech Blog",
        "description":"A CMS-style blog site similar to a Wordpress site, where developers can publish their blog posts and comment on other developers’ posts as well.",  
        "url":"https://not-another-tech-blog-78.herokuapp.com/",
        "imgurl":"src/assets/techblog.png"
      },
      {
        "name":"Weather App",
        "description":"Weather app that provides current and future weather forecasts in cities.",
        "url":"https://grocha78.github.io/How-Is-It-Over-There/",
        "imgurl":"src/assets/weatherapp.png"
      }
    ],
```

How can the clickable web links for each project show individually? Right now it just shows them but they are unclickable.

I've tried adding 4 different <a sections but this just shows 4 rows of the image shown in the pictures of my Portfolio section.
I've added the weblink to the href section for each project and it does show only the 1 row that is currently seen but the links are all bunched together and it doesn't work.
I'm not too sure on what to do next and I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: It's not clear what the issue(s) is(are). To be clickable they need to either be links, or have an associated click handler. How they're displayed depends on the elements and their associated CSS.

Comment: Instead of <h6>{item.url}</h6> why not <a href={item.url}>{item.url}</a>?

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much! I was trying to figure out how to add the <a href to that area but I did not think to add it the way you suggested. Thanks again!